# How to set focus to the datatable filter?

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, focus, webix

I'm using a Webix datatable with some filters and want to be able to set the focus to some particular filter input, for instance, after initialization. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do so.

A minimal required configuration is

```
{      
  view:"datatable",
  columns:[
    { id:"id"},
    { id:"value",   header:{content:"textFilter"}, fillspace:true}        
  ],
  data:list_data,
  ready:function(){
    alert("datatable loaded")    
  }

}
```

http://webix.com/snippet/ba52bfc1

But how can I get filter's id or object and set the focus to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ready:function(){
    this.getFilter("value").focus();
}
```

Updated snippet : http://webix.com/snippet/b4f50020